# jQuery addClass/removeClass working during debugging but not regular execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to run through a series of elements and toggle each's opacity for a given amount of time before returning to normal.  I've tried using delay, queue, and a sleep function but haven't had any luck. Oddly enough, I just noticed that when I'm in debug mode, things work exactly as expected.  However, outside of debug mode things do not work at all. Here's what I'm currently trying to run in a forEach() loop:

```
$currEl.toggleClass("light");
sleep(1000);
$currEl.toggleClass('light');
```

Here's the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/qdzsws7b/

Answer (score 0):

Busy waiting can be dangerous. Try to make "sequence" and "index" global variables, then toggle class with setTimeout.

```
var currSequence, currIndex;
function playSequence(sequence){
    currSequence = sequnece;
    currIndex = 0;
    changeLight();
}
function changeLight(){
    if (currIndex > 0){
        $('#' + mapping[currSequence[currIndex - 1]]).toggleClass('light');
    }
    $('#' + mapping[currSequence[currIndex++]]).toggleClass('light');
    if(currIndex < currSequence.length)
        setTimeout(changeLight, 1000);
}
```